# What does margin is this? (PageMenu, swift, non-storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift

[simulator ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYwvJ.png)

I have used PageMenu Library.

I have used swift and not story-board.

https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu

### How do I remove this margin ?

The following is source code.

ProjectDetailViewController.swift

```
class ProjectDetailViewController : UIViewController, CAPSPageMenuDelegate{

    var projectId:NSInteger!
    var firstView: FirstViewController!
    var secondView: SecondViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.title = "PageMenu"
        firstView = FirstViewController()
        secondView = SecondViewController()
        firstView.title = "test1"
        secondView.title = "test2"

        var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []
        controllerArray.append(firstView)
        controllerArray.append(secondView)

        let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
            .MenuItemSeparatorWidth(0.0),
            .UseMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
            .MenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.0),
            .SelectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.hex("#ffee58", alpha: 1)),
            .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.hex("#fffde7", alpha: 1)),
            .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.hex("#ffee58", alpha: 1)),
        ]

        let topMargin:CGFloat = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height+self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

        let pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, topMargin, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height-topMargin), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

        pageMenu.delegate = self

        self.addChildViewController(pageMenu)
        self.view.addSubview(pageMenu.view)
        pageMenu.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }

    func willMoveToPage(controller: UIViewController, index: Int){
        NSLog("willMoveToPage");
    }

    func didMoveToPage(controller: UIViewController, index: Int){
        NSLog("didMoveToPage");
    }
}
```

FirstViewController.swift

```
class FirstViewController:UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSLog("x = %f y = %f width = %f height = %f", self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    }
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
class SecondViewController:UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: use this code in viewDidLoad of FirstViewController  `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: @El Captain Your post Speed and accurate answer is amazing. thanks!